# Build TGUI basic example with CMake and g++?

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I would like to build a basic example using TGUI, but I get thousands of errors. Note that I can build the project from this command:

```
g++ main.cpp -ltgui -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system
```

Here the `main.cpp`:

```
#include <TGUI/TGUI.hpp>
#include <TGUI/Backend/SFML-Graphics.hpp>

bool runExample(tgui::BackendGui& gui)
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window{ {800, 600}, "TGUI example - SFML_GRAPHICS backend" };

    tgui::Gui gui{window};
    if (runExample(gui))
        gui.mainLoop();
}
```

And my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(TestProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
find_package(TGUI 0.10 REQUIRED)

if(NOT SFML_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find SFML")
endif()

if(NOT TGUI_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find TGUI")
endif()

add_executable(TestProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestProject ${TGUI_LIBRARY} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

I did:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..
-- Found SFML 2.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SFML
-- Found TGUI 0.10.0 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/TGUI
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/canard/tgui-example/build
$ make
In file included from /usr/include/TGUI/Vector2.hpp:30,
             from /usr/include/TGUI/Layout.hpp:30,
             from /usr/include/TGUI/Animation.hpp:29,
             from /usr/include/TGUI/Core.hpp:30,
             from /usr/include/TGUI/TGUI.hpp:30,
             from /home/canard/tgui-example/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/TGUI/String.hpp:86:39: error: ‘enable_if_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
   86 |         using IsStringViewType = std::enable_if_t<
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/TGUI/String.hpp:86:34: note: ‘std::enable_if_t’ is only available from C++14 onwards
   86 |         using IsStringViewType = std::enable_if_t<
...
```

Comment: What if you switch to C++14 or newer?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Much better with `C++17`, but this time I have an issue with the linker. Lots of undefined references `main.cpp:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'`

Comment: With `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` on, I notice that the libraries are not added during link: `/usr/bin/c++  -std=c++17 -Wall -rdynamic CMakeFiles/boids.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/boids.dir/boids.cpp.o CMakeFiles/boids.dir/vector2.cpp.o -o boids `

Comment: For SFML 2.5 a call to `find_package(SFML)` defines IMPORTED **targets** like `sfml-system` or `sfml-graphics`. It is described in the script [SFMLConfig.cmake](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/2.5.x/cmake/SFMLConfig.cmake.in) which you have under  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SFML` directory. That script doesn't define variable `SFML_LIBRARIES` which you are using in your code. (You could print value of that variable and find that it is empty.)